# Using a given font for ASCII and another for unicode

Tags: emacs, unicode, emacsw32, fontconfig

I would like to set up emacs so that it uses

```
-outline-Courier New-normal-normal-normal-mono-16-*-*-*-c-*-iso8859-1
```

to display ASCII characters and

```
-outline-Arial Unicode MS-normal-normal-normal-sans-16-*-*-*-p-*-gb2312.1980*-*
```

to display unicode symbols.

This is actually how it was set up by default on one of the computer I use.
On another, pressing `C-u C-x =` on a unicode character of interest gives

```
        character: ↷ (8631, #o20667, #x21b7)
preferred charset: unicode (Unicode (ISO10646))
       code point: 0x21B7
           syntax: .    which means: punctuation
         category: .:Base
      buffer code: #xE2 #x86 #xB7
        file code: #xE2 #x86 #xB7 (encoded by coding system utf-8-dos)
          display: no font available

Character code properties: customize what to show
  name: CLOCKWISE TOP SEMICIRCLE ARROW
  general-category: So (Symbol, Other)

There are text properties here:
  fontified            t
```

which I do not fully understand but the part `display: no font available` is not what I would like.

How can I change that?

Comment: Find out the difference between the two computers. This [article](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts) might help.

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 so one solution would be to treat everything as unicode. Or perhaps you mean something different?

Comment: I do. I want to have a different font `plain text' and `'symbols and stuffs'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the page of interest is not the one entitled `Set Fonts` but `Font Sets` (see [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FontSets)).
I added

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'unicode
              "-outline-Arial Unicode MS-normal-normal-normal-sans-*-*-*-*-p-*-gb2312.1980-0")
```

to my .emacs and it did the trick.